# WordPress can't get page ID from sidebar file?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I need to highlight some menu items differently depending on the page ID and so when I call the sidebar up top I have this

```
<?php if( is_page('my-page') )echo 'my-page';?>
```

The echo is just for me to see if it is working...
But, it is not. I put the same code into the main page template and it outputs yes I am on that page.  Any reason why the sidebar would not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [is_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) :

Cannot Be Used Inside The Loop

This tag must be used BEFORE The Loop and does not work inside The Loop

Due to certain global variables being overwritten during The Loop is_page() will not work. In order to use it after The Loop you must call wp_query_reset() after The Loop.

Maybe this is why you're experiencing problems ?

Comment: Thank you! That was it, I did not think that, and still am not sure how, the get_sidebar() call is inside the loop...? I added the query reset right above where I call the sidebar and it works. But the loop is already closed isn't it?

Comment: can't tell if the loop is closed unless i see some code , usualy the loop closes before the sidebar is called but in some cases there might be an aditional loop in the sidebar ( a plugin calling it or whatever , there usualy is a second loop )